# how to apply chunking for the below tagged pos ? (nltk)

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

```
from nltk import word_tokenize, pos_tag, pos_tag_sents
tagged_pos = pos_tag_sents(map(word_tokenize, data))
tagged_pos
```

> the following are pos tags:
> [('dpdb', 'NN'),('engine', 'NN'),('bottom', 'NN'),('power', 'NN'),('gain', 'NN'),('curve', 'NN'),
> ('every', 'DT')],[('dpdb', 'NN'),('engine', 'NN'),('center', 'NN'),('power', 'NN'),('gain', 'NN'),
> ('curve', 'NN'),('every', 'DT')]]

I tried with:

```
grammar = "NP: {<DT>?<JJ>*<NN>}"
chunk_parse = nltk.RegexpParser(grammar)

chunked=[]
for s in tagged_pos:
    chunked.append(chunk_parse.parse(s))
```

got the following output:
Warning: parsing empty text
Warning: parsing empty text
Warning: parsing empty text
Warning: parsing empty text
Warning: parsing empty text
Warning: parsing empty text
Warning: parsing empty text

Comment: Did you have a look at the examples provided in the [NLTK's documentation on chunking](http://www.nltk.org/howto/chunk.html)?

Comment: Please provide a complete [MWE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and add detailed information what is wrong with the result you are getting?

Comment: after trying.. I got like this

Warning: parsing empty text
Warning: parsing empty text
Warning: parsing empty text
Warning: parsing empty text
Warning: parsing empty text
Warning: parsing empty text

Comment: Could you please update the question so that it contains complete information? Adding this information in comments (and poorly formatted) is really not helpful at all.